# Getting import error when I try to compile with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have multiple python files which have modules I've created in them. The files depend on each other for modules.

Currently, I have all of them in one folder

```
main.py  
readfile.py  
pronunciation.py  
meaning.py  
classes.py
```

The only modules I've used are the inbuilt random (Which I'm not sure how to add in either). Here is my current code

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = []
includes = ['classes.py','pronunciation.py','readfile.py','meaning.py']
excludes = []
packages = []

setup(name = 'Revision',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'Revision program for studying',
      author = '',
      author_email = '',
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
      executables = [Executable('main.py')])
```

From this, I'm getting an ImportError, saying that the module classes.py does not exists (It is imported in meaning.py), how do I fix this? Also, I'm worried that cx_freeze might not import random.

Am on windows too, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
includes = ['classes.py','pronunciation.py','readfile.py','meaning.py']
```

with

```
includes = ['classes','pronunciation','readfile','meaning']
```

this list contains modules to be imported during building.
In Python we don't specify *.py extension in imports.

BTW. In Python's terms    *.py files  =  modules, it's the same.